# How to capture a tabOut event for an HTML element like button?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, extjs

Using Javascript (ExtJS), how can I add an event listener for tab out of a button. I know, blur() is one way but this will also fire when the element loose focus because of other events like mouseout etc.

I want to be able to distinguish a **Tabout** from these other event. Is it possible?

```
//event parameter gives me no information whether its tab key or mouse
//btn is Ext.button.Button...
btn.on('blur', function (obj, event) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keydown event:

```
$("button").on("keydown", function(e) {
   if(e.which === 9) {
       console.log("Tab pressed");
   }
});
```

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ym4Tm/1/)